# Doctrine 2, undefined entity method findOneBy*

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I have a strange issue. Here is the error message:

Call to undefined method `MyProject\BlogBundle\Entity\Blog::findOneById()`

I have setup the mapping, the entity class was created using the console and I have updated the schema in the database. What could be causing this issue?

I'm using symfony2. Here is the line:

```
$blogRepo = $this->get('myproject.blog.repository.blog');  
$blog = $blogRepo->findOneById($id);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

findOneById doesn't exist, try

> $blogRepo->findOneBy(array('id' => $id));

where 'id' is an existing field in your Entity.

You can check the Doctrine's class documentation here: [EntityRepository](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/2.0/api)

Edit: looks like findOneById does exist as long as the entity has a field "Id". [Check the docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-simple-conditions). Thx to Ryall for pointing it out

Comment: Yes, and also `$entity = $em->getRepository('VendorSomeBundle:Post')->findOneById($id)` would work too. BUT you have to make sure the Post entity HAS the attribute. It is important to remember that the repository IS NOT the equivalent of symfony1's `*Table` class.  The entity sould know already the mapping and relationships and preferences.

Comment: `findOneById` is a valid magic method, assuming there is an `id` field on the entity. http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-simple-conditions

Answer (score 5):

What is the service definition of `myproject.blog.repository.blog`? It looks like you are mapping it to `MyProject\BlogBundle\Entity\Blog` while it really should be `MyProject\BlogBundle\Entity\BlogRepository`.

Instead of creating your own Repository class you can also have one created on the fly by the EntityManager.

```
$user = $em->getRepository('MyProject\Domain\User')->find($id);
```

Or even shorter:

```
$user = $em->find('MyProject\Domain\User', $id);
```

Taken from [the Doctrine2 ORM Documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/working-with-objects.html).

Comment: I'd like to understand what you mean by `MyProject\Domain\*` is this an `Entity` class?

Comment: Yes, `MyProject\Domain\User` is an entity.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$blogRepo = $this->getRepository('myproject.blog.repository.blog');  
$blog = $blogRepo->findOneById($id);
```

**getRepository**