# Preferred Choices for Entity Field - Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I've added an entity field type to a form I'm using but when I try to set preferred_choices I get the following error message

> Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given in /srv/www/amber/public_html/Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Form/Type/DoctrineType.php line 98

You can see the code below

```
    $builder->add('candStatus', 'entity', array(
        'label' => 'Candidate Status', 
        'class' => 'AmberAtsBundle:SelCandStatus',
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('sc')
            ->orderBy('sc.rank', 'ASC');
            },
         'property' => 'candStatus',
         'preferred_choices' => array('1'),
        ));
```

I'm fairly new to Symfony, so any help would be appreciated

Comment: Pretty sure that its a problem related to Entity .. post code of the entity if possible..

Comment: I've looked around a bit more, and found the answer within the following 2 question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776867/set-default-value-of-choice-field-symfony-formtype
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425819/doctrine-2-undefined-entity-method-findoneby

I've removed the preferred_choices from the formType, and instead added some code to the controller to pre populate the object before it is used to create the form. I'll post more detail when I can answer in a few hours time

Comment: You can use the getReference method for entity manager to construct an array that will work for 'preferred_choices' on an entity form field. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073236/symfony2-setting-a-default-choice-field-selection/17413107#17413107)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to pass into your form an `EntityRepository` (or similar) and actually provide a collection of entities to `preferred_choices`. From memory, in previous versions of Symfony it would permit an array of entity IDs, but not now.

Probably `preferred_choices` should also be a callback, like `query_builder`.

The code that actually determines if something from `preferred_choices` matches a particular choices is below. It's just a simple PHP `array_search()`.

**Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\ChoiceList [#](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/ChoiceList/ChoiceList.php#L386)**

```
protected function isPreferred($choice, array $preferredChoices)
{
    return false !== array_search($choice, $preferredChoices, true);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

This is what works with Symfony 2.7:

```
$builder->add('license', 'entity', [
    'class' => 'CmfcmfMediaModule:License\LicenseEntity',
    'preferred_choices' => function (LicenseEntity $license) {
        return !$license->isOutdated();
    },
    // ...
])
```

`preferred_choices` needs an anonymous function which is called for each entity and must return true or false depending on whether it's preferred or not.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as of Symfony 2.7.

Comment: Im using SF 2.8 and it work for me. But the accepted one didnt.

Answer (score 1):

From your example, where you want to get the first result as the prefered choice, you have to return the entity with the first rank and not its index.

To do so, you can retrive it in the controller then pass it as a parameter in `$options`:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    //prevent error if $options['prefered_choices'] is not set
    $prefered_choices = isset($options['prefered_choices']) ? $options['prefered_choices'] : array();
    $builder->add('candStatus', 'entity', array(
        'label' => 'Candidate Status', 
        'class' => 'AmberAtsBundle:SelCandStatus',
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('sc')
                ->orderBy('sc.rank', 'ASC')
            ;
        },
        'property' => 'candStatus',
        'preferred_choices' => $prefered_choices,
    ));
    //...
}
```

You can also use `getReference`, as j_goldman noted [in their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277046/preferred-choices-for-entity-field-symfony2#comment30671334_17277046), but since your ranks can change (I think), I don't think it fit well for your use case:

```
$builder->add('candStatus', 'entity', array(
    'label' => 'Candidate Status', 
    'class' => 'AmberAtsBundle:SelCandStatus',
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('sc')
            ->orderBy('sc.rank', 'ASC')
        ;
    },
    'property' => 'candStatus',
    'prefered_choices' => $this->em->getReference('AmberAtsBundle:SelCandStatus', 1),
));
```

Finally, you can use a callback returning the chosen entity, for example with the same DQL you used with a limit of 1: (It's what I would do)

```
$builder->add('candStatus', 'entity', array(
    'label' => 'Candidate Status', 
    'class' => 'AmberAtsBundle:SelCandStatus',
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('sc')
            ->orderBy('sc.rank', 'ASC')
        ;
    },
    'property' => 'candStatus',
    'preferred_choices' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('sc')
            ->orderBy('sc.rank', 'ASC')
            ->setMaxResults(1)
        ;
    },
));
```

Comment: your last example will not work. you are given the entity object, not the Repository in the preferred_choices closure. At least this was the only object i was geting.

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony3 the following works for me:

```
'preferred_choices' => function($entity) {
                $preferred = [1, 2];
                $choices = [];

                if(in_array($entity->getId(), $preferred)) {
                    $choices[] = $entity;
                }

                return $choices;
            },
```