# passing variable in findOneBy array not working

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to pass variable to my find statement. it works when i pass direct values for instance: `findOneByUserId(1);` but not when I pass a defined variable in the controller `findOneBy(array('user_id' => $userId));`. I have also tried `findOneBy(array('index' => $userId ->getId()));`without success and I can confirm the value of userId is passed to the controller.

Anybody please...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425819/doctrine-2-undefined-entity-method-findoneby

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get an entity having a ManyToOne related to a User

```
$repository->findOneBy(array('user' => $user));
```

Where $user is an entity.

```
$repository->findOneBy(array('user' => $userId));
```

Also works, if $userId is $user->getId();

---

If you are trying to get an User with its id

```
$repository->find($userId);
```

or

```
$repository->findOneBy(array('id' => $userId));
```

Comment: Actually, I have a field called user_id different from the field id where id is the primary. I tried your suggestion and I get Null.

Comment: i also see "Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in ..." when I use getId() at the end of the statement.

Comment: Ok, first of all, what entity/repository are you searching for ? An User ?